# EF 4.1 code first Invalid column name "User_UserId"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can't figure out why this is causing EF error: Invalid column name 'User_UserId' when saving in EF.

Here is my model:

```
 [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<FriendList> FriendLists { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class FriendList
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Guid FriendListId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("FriendUser")]
    public virtual Guid FriendUserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual User FriendUser { get; set; }
}
```

basically, its one to many relationship with users having a friendlists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have *two* navigation properties of type `User` in your `FriendList` class. EF cannot figure out which of these belong to `User.FriendLists` and then creates for all *three* navigation properties a separate one-to-many relationship, one of them has the default foreign key name `User_UserId`.

You can overwrite this convention with the `InverseProperty` attribute:

```
public class FriendList
{
    // ...

    [DataMember]
    [InverseProperty("FriendLists")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Now, `User.FriendLists` and `FriendList.User` are the endpoints of the same one-to-many relationship and `FriendList.FriendUser` defines a second one-to-many relationship (but without an endpoint in the `User` class).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation of the endpoint and the EF attribute solution. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess:

1) The attribute ForeignKey in your case must be set as `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` and not as `[ForeignKey("User")]`

2) Or If one of these classes are not mapped you must set the attribute [NotMapped] on it;

Answer (score 0):

Your ForeignKey attribute is in the wrong place.

Try this:

```
[DataMember]
public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual User User { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual Guid FriendUserId { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[ForeignKey("FriendUserId")]
public virtual User FriendUser { get; set; }
```

At least it worked for me.